# Set borders for words to convert to new string by specific character or word count exceeding specific length?

Tags: r

So I scraped this string from google

```
"Raveena Tandon (born 26 October 1974) is an Indian actress who works in Hindi films."
```

Basically I want to confirm that the first couple words in the search result is an actual name, and not just some random description. I intend on confirming this by placing boundaries only a name would fit in. Which is usually no more then 4 words.

Considering Wikipedia typically formats people topic results in this manner;

-person name- (-age info-).

I'd need to confirm "(" exists at the end of the name which should have a length no more then 4 words. This means the name could have 2 words, 3 words, just as long as the new string's border stops counting at either a length of 4 words or at a "("

This would be the desired output.

```
"Raveena Tandon"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, using `str_extract` from the package `stringr`:

**Data**:

```
string <- "Raveena Tandon (born 26 October 1974) is an Indian actress who works in Hindi films."
```

**Solution**:

```
str_extract(string, "([A-Z][a-z]+\\s){1,4}(?=\\()")
```

The regex has the following components:

`[A-Z]` matches any uppercase letter occurring once

`[a-z]+` matches any sequence (of length 1 to infinite) of lower case letters

`\\s` matches 1 white space character

`{1,4}` is a quantifying expression determining that the preceding capture group, namely `([A-Z][a-z]+\\s)`, matches at least once and at most four times

`(?=\\()` is positive look-ahead; it "says": match ... if you see `(?=\\()` on the right-hand side. In this case the thing to be "seen" is the opening round bracket `(`, which in regex is a metacharacter with different meanings than the literal `(`. To match it, it needs to be 'escaped' by `\\`.

**Result**:

```
[1] "Raveena Tandon "
```

**EDIT**:

To get rid of the white space character at the end of the match, you can include `\\s` within the look-ahead; then it is not consumed by the match:

```
str_extract(string, "([A-Z][a-z\\s]+){1,4}(?=\\s\\()")
[1] "Raveena Tandon"
```

Comment: Okay interesting. Could you dissect each step for me so I can understand what's happening. This is great btw cheers.

Comment: Okay cool. How would we adjust it so the space at the end of the string isn't present. Can the borders always be set by the last character instead of the last space? I take it this is because we're matching the \\s ?

Comment: This is it: `str_extract(string, "([A-Z][a-z\\s]+){1,4}(?=\\s\\()")`

Comment: Oh I think I understand, so before hand it was considering a space to be a matched word. Now we're associating a space to match together within all characters a-z? That's my guess, i'm probably wrong lol.

Comment: No quite: `[a-z\\s]` is a character class, consisting, in this case, of any lower-case letter and a white space character. The nice thing about character classes is that **order** does not matter; so you can match a `\\s` preceding a letter or following it.

Comment: Oh almost forgot to mention. I'd want to consider "," to be a usable character as well. Does this account for all symbols besides "(" instead of just a-z characters

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `,` is, at any rate, **not** a metacharacter, so you can match it literally.

Comment: Okay cool. I knew it wasn't a metacharacter, just didn't quite understand what characters we were assuming with A-Z. This is great stuff man, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: No prob. Cheers